# Why were the answers on this closed question deleted?

Tags: support

Why were the answers to [this closed question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/240311/help-with-fictional-scenario-trapped-in-lagrange-point-orbit) deleted?

[image: screencap]

I was browsing the answers to a Q migrated from SE:Space Exploration when suddenly they were all marked as deleted and the Q was closed. Refreshing the page, the answers were all gone. I'm not asking why the Q was closed, because that's obvious, but why were the answers deleted? They contained some genuinely interesting info. Are answers normally deleted on migrated Q's that are closed? Did the answering users delete their posts simultaneously? What happened?

Answer (score 5):

Migrated questions which get closed on the receiving site get returned to the original site, with all the answers.

As a consequence, answers to the question get deleted on the receiving site.

Comment: Ah, one has to access [the Q on the original site](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/61444/help-with-fictional-scenario-trapped-in-lagrange-point-orbit) to see the answers now. Thanks 